# No matching function for call to 'MatToUIImage'

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, opencv3.0, objective-c++

I am using the OpenCV Contrib framework to preform facial recognition. I need to convert a cv::Mat to a UIImage. However, when I call the `MatToUIImage` function I get an error.

```
No matching function for call to 'MatToUIImage'
```

This is the code I am using...

```
MatToUIImage(face, outcome);
```

`face` is a cv::Mat and `outcome` is a UIImage.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [open source on GitHub](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgcodecs/include/opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h), it looks like the prototype is actually:

```
UIImage* MatToUIImage(const cv::Mat& image);
```

which means the function you really want only takes one parameter (your `cv::Mat`) and it returns the `UIImage`.

I.E.

```
UIImage *outcome = MatToUIImage(face);
```